# Как узнать сколько памяти занимает каждая переменная в скрипте PHP

Tags: php, отладка

Появилась необходимость узнать, сколько занимает `ОЗУ` каждая переменная в скрипте PHP. Есть ли способы, кроме прописывания миллион раз `memory_get_usage()`?

Comment: Вот ответ на английском SO:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192657/how-to-determine-the-memory-footprint-size-of-a-variable

Comment: @GinoPane, стоит перевести и добавить как ответ :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function sizeofvar($var) {
    $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
    $tmp = unserialize(serialize($var));
    return memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

переводить  и копипастить немогу, да и смысл.?

могу посоветовать тот инструмент, которым пользовался, есть **xdebug**, включен в phpExpertEditor PHPDesigner и в стандартную библиотеку ПХП но отключеа в php.ini

дальше можно загуглить xdebud и настроить его под себя. Он не сложный.

Comment: почему столько минусов ? xdebug показывает сколько и после каких действий  было скушано ресурсов, в чем проблема ????